# MySQL: Convert Unencrypted Password Column to MD5 Hash

Tags: php, mysql, database, md5

I'm migrating a lot of user data into a new system and the previous developer did not MD5 his password column.

Is there a way to run a query on the `password` column and convert the values to MD5?

Comment: If you're starting anew and have the choice, there's no reason to pick MD5. It's old and has been considered relatively insecure for a long time. Ideally you would use a PBKDF or at least a salted hash, but if you're going to use a bare hash then at least use something from the SHA-2 family of hashes (such as SHA-256). PHP and MySQL both support them and they are much more secure than MD5.

Comment: @JeremyBanks So it's suggested to "don't use MD5" (which is good), but then *recommend* to "use SHA-x" for password hashes? They are "stronger", sure, but suffer from the *same pitfalls* as MD5 for password hashes: *they are not designed for it*. (See bcrypt, scrypt, etc. for well-proven problem-specific solutions.)

Comment: Also, I feel that it is worth mentioning in an emphasized fashion: **without a good salt, MD5 (or SHA-x) are useless for password hashes**.

Comment: And one last nit: hashing is *not* encryption. (I suggest using an existing library to handle authentication - and preferably one that is well-tested where the authors studied this topic well - as security is hard to get correct ..)

Comment: @pst You're right, of course. I did acknowledge that a PBKDF would be best, and yes, unsalted hashes of any sort are very weak to rainbow tables. However I thought that the suggestion of just changing the hash function was about five times more likely to be followed than anything else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MySQL has builtin MD5, just add a new column and set the encrypted value there:

```
UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = MD5(password);
```

If you're happy with the result, drop the original password column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in SQL - just use the `MD5()` function:
`insert into my_new_table select username,MD5(password) from old_table`